Finding coordinate transfromations by line element

I’m confused on how to generally approach these coordinate transformations: I initially thought we can set $dT^2=(dt-b/2dx)^2$ and $a^2dX^2= (a^2+\frac{b^2}{4})dx^2$. This way, when carrying out the calculation, we get $-dt^2+bdxdt +a^2dx^2=-dT^2+a^2dX^2$, which is the result we want (correct?). But then I can actually get the explicit transformation by integrating, since b is constant and a(t) does not depend on x, which should not be possible according to the exercise. So it seems that I am either doing something wrong or not understanding how to solve this type of problem in general. Some help and an explanation of how to do it would help me out a ton.

Note that in the original metric, $a$ is a function of $t$, while in the FRW metric, $a$ is a function of $T$; it should probably be named $A$ to avoid confusion. Will your new $a$ be a function of only $T$? Try to make your transformation as explicit as possible.
